# Hide seperator when response is empty

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation, is-empty

I am trying to select the address, zipcode, city and country of my customers from the database. I want to show these columns in one column. So I am using CONCAT_WS to select the address details of my customers:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', address, zip, city, country) AS address2 FROM customers
```

When there is data in my table I get the correct response:

```
Street, 1234, City, Belgium
```

When there is no data, The statement shows only the comma`s:

```
, , , Belgium
```

I want to hide these comma`s if there is no data. Does someone know how I can hide these comma`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONCAT_WS() ignores NULLs, but it does not ignore empty strings like `''`. These are not the same thing in MySQL.

To work around this, you can use the [NULLIF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif). This returns NULL if its two arguments are equal.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', 
    NULLIF(address, ''), 
    NULLIF(zip, ''), 
    NULLIF(city, ''), 
    NULLIF(country, '')
  ) AS address2 FROM customers
```